# Render components based on the data from a multidimensional array in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, map-function

I have an array with items which can have even or odd number of items. I made a function which puts each two elements in their own array inside a main array, so it looks like this at the end;

```
items array: [{}, {}, {}, {}]
returned array: [[{}, {}], [{}, {}]]

items array: [{}, {}, {}]
returned array: [[{}, {}], [{}, undefined]]
```

I did this because I want to render each Bootstrap row with two columns on the page. Now, I'm not sure how to implement mapping through this array. To a certain extent I know how to do this;

1. Map through returned array.
2. If second element in current array is `undefined` return a row with just one item.
3. If both elements are defined in current array return a row with both items.

But by React rules I need to add additional `key` attributes to the elements I return with `map` so I would need to somehow keep the track of `index` variable. What would be the efficient way to do this?

Comment: `I did this because I want to render each Bootstrap row with two columns on the page.`  I personally think your going about this the wrong way, bootstrap is a responsive layout engine, you shouldn't be having to hard code column breaks,. just set your `col-md-6 cols-xs-12` etc grid rules.

Comment: @Keith I know that but I need to create a row for every two (or the last one) element, otherwise it won't display well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't think of a nice way to `map` your original array, but you could use a for loop and increment by 2 each iteration and just check if the second element is truthy before using it.

**Example**

```
class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const content = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < itemsArray.length; i += 2) {
      content.push(
        <div class="row" key={i}>
          <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="option correct-option">{itemsArray[i].text}</div>
          </div>
          {itemsArray[i + 1] && (
            <div class="col-md-6">
              <div class="option correct-option">{itemsArray[i + 1].text}</div>
            </div>
          )}
        </div>
      );
    }

    return <div>{content}</div>;
  }
}
```

If you want to use the array of arrays, you could `map` it and just check if the second element in the array is truthy before using it.

**Example**

```
class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {itemsArray.map((items, index) => {
          <div class="row" key={index}>
            <div class="col-md-6">
              <div class="option correct-option">{items[0].text}</div>
            </div>
            {items[1] && (
              <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="option correct-option">{items[1].text}</div>
              </div>
            )}
          </div>;
        })}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```